DockOvpn: TLS key negotiation timeout
I am running alekslitvinenk/openvpn (aka "DockOvpn") with the following docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3'

volumes:
    dockovpn:

networks:
    frontend:

services:
    dockovpn:
        image: alekslitvinenk/openvpn
        container_name: dockovpn
        restart: always
        cap_add:
            - NET_ADMIN
        ports:
            - '1194:1194/udp'
        networks:
            - frontend
        volumes:
            - dockovpn:/opt/Dockovpn_data
        command:
            - --regenerate

This has been working great - but since some time recently the OpenVPN client is not able to connect any more. These are the last lines in the OpenVPN client's log:
Wed May  1 15:53:41 2024 UDPv4 link local: (not bound)
Wed May  1 15:53:41 2024 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]xxx:1194
Wed May  1 15:53:41 2024 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1714575221,WAIT,,,,,,
Wed May  1 15:53:42 2024 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1714575222,AUTH,,,,,,
Wed May  1 15:53:42 2024 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]xxx:1194, sid=3053ee6a 64729182
Wed May  1 15:53:42 2024 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=Easy-RSA CA
Wed May  1 15:53:42 2024 VERIFY KU OK
Wed May  1 15:53:42 2024 Validating certificate extended key usage
Wed May  1 15:53:42 2024 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Wed May  1 15:53:42 2024 VERIFY EKU OK
Wed May  1 15:53:42 2024 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=MyReq
Wed May  1 15:54:41 2024 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Wed May  1 15:54:41 2024 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Wed May  1 15:54:41 2024 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Wed May  1 15:54:41 2024 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1714575281,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,,,,
Wed May  1 15:54:41 2024 Restart pause, 128 second(s)

For some reason I am getting a timeout during TLS key negotiation. This indicates a firewall issue, but port 1194 UDP is open in the firewall for the docker host (as it was always). And the initial connection does seem to work - just the TLS handshake times out (unless I am misinterpreting the log output).
I tried to go back to older versions of DockOvpn, in case a container update broke the functionality. But it does not seem to be directly related to the version.
To confirm that the UDP port is in fact open I used netcat - i.e.:

I started nc -u -l 1194 on the docker host machine.
I started nc -u <docker-host-ip> 1194 on another machine from a different network.
I sent Hi from the latter machine.
Hi appeared on the docker host.

I also confirmed via
docker container ls --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}" -a

that UDP traffic on port 1194 is forwarded to the correct container:
CONTAINER ID   NAMES                    PORTS
e59843152f14   dockovpn                 0.0.0.0:1194->1194/udp, :::1194->1194/udp, 8080/tcp

(Port 8080 is not exposed deliberately). The OpenVPN client config file looks like this (sans keys):
client
dev tun
proto udp
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher AES-256-GCM
auth SHA512
verb 3
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
remote example.com 1194
…

I also tried connecting from 3 different ISP's that worked previously, just in case something has changed with one of them. But no luck there.
Does anyone have an idea what else could be wrong in the network setup here? 
Update:
I also checked the iptables entries created by docker compose, but they look correct to me:
$ iptables-save | grep -P "(--to-destination|--.port)" | grep -v "DROP" | grep -P ":\d+|--dport \d+"
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.3/32 ! -i br-7dc70774aca7 -o br-7dc70774aca7 -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.3/32 -d 172.18.0.3/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER ! -i br-7dc70774aca7 -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.3:1194

I also did the same netcat test as described above between the docker host and the docker container and this worked as well.
I also confirmed with tcpdump -qni any port 1194 on the docker host that the UDP traffic from the OpenVPN client is correctly arriving at the docker host.
So I am still at a loss here. The communication between the docker host and the docker container (or the service inside the container) seems to fail somewhere.
I have since given up and am running the OpenVPN server now directly on the docker host (via https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install), which is working fine.

To troubleshoot OpenVPN issues, protocol TCP is required, so kill the server and make these changes (UDP should be used when not troubleshooting): Server Config: verb 4, proto tcp | Client Config: verb 5, proto tcp. Once done, start the server and connect with the client, then please post both the server and client logs after the connection attempt fails (note: is that Docker image running an old version of OpenVPN, as it also appears the really old TLS-Crypt is being used instead of TLS-Auth since key-direction is for TLS-Crypt, which has been depreciated for >5yrs)

As initially mentioned, it's the DockOvpn image. In the latest version it is based on Alpine Linux 3.14.1 which is 3 years old. So yeah, may be that is the issue after all? Though nobody else seems to have such issues with it.
Otherwise yes, good tip debugging with TCP rather than UDP.
